# Intercepting webpage requests through Wireless Hosted Network

Tags: c#, .net

Good Evening,

I have created a Wireless Hosted Network on my Windows 8 Laptop, via the following 2 batch commands:
"netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=testing key=12345678"
and
"netsh wlan start hostednetwork"

Afterwards, a device (Android-based mobile phone) is able to connect successfully to this Wireless Hosted Network hosted on my laptop. I've also created a HttpListener on port 1234 in C#, which the device can successfully access by using the built in web browser to access:

```
http://192.168.138.1:1234
```

**However, how would the host (I.E. my laptop) intercept and redirect webpage requests? That is, how would a .NET program running on my laptop be notified when a device tries to access any webpage, say, google.com or facebook.com, and then redirect the device to another webpage by sending this webpage to it instead?**

I have tried the following:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/");
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        while (true)
        {
            var c = listener.GetContext();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection");
            string response = "<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br></BODY></HTML>"; //Redirects device to this
            byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
            c.Response.ContentLength64 = b.Length;
            c.Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            c.Response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
```

However, the program running on my laptop does not pick up anything at all when I use the device to access any webpage (E.G. google.com). Sorry if I have asked a repeated question, I couldn't find it anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up your own DNS server for this to work. The problem is that your laptop makes a DNS query for google.com and receives an IP which points to Google's servers and not yours.

Or, if there is only a few sites you want to redirect - add entries for them in your `hosts` file.